# Getting "String index out of range: -7"

Tags: javascript

I am trying to click a button using the code

```
driver.findElement(By.id("ContentPlaceHolderView_ctlRegistration_CustomerDetail_Button2")).click();
```

but i am getting error saying `String index out of range: -7` . Can someone please let me know why i am getting this error.The same code worked fine for one test method, but its not working for another method.Thanks in advance, Manasa

Comment: What library are you using?

Comment: are you using plain javascript or some libraries?

Comment: We are not using any library